# Error in m == q : R comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

The whole function which i need to convert the for loop in to apply for optimization

```
plans_achievements <- function(pa_m,pa_q){
             if(nrow(pa_m)==0 & nrow(pa_q==0)){
                df = data.frame(a = c(""), b = c("No Data Available"))
                colnames(df)=""
              }else{
                pa_m= pa_m%>% select(inc,month_year,Plans,Achievements,quarter_year)
                colnames(pa_mon)[2] = "Period"
        
        pa_q= pa_q%>% select(inc,quarter_year,Plans,Achievements)
        colnames(pa_qtr)[2] = "Period"
        
        df = data.frame(inc=c(""),Period=c(""),Plans=c(""),Achievements=c(""))
        
        for (q in unique(pa_q$Period)){
          df1 = pa_q[pa_q$Period==q,]
          df1$Period = paste0("<span style=\"color:#288D55\">",df1$Period,"</span>")
          df1$Plans = paste0("<span style=\"color:#288D55\">",df1$Plans,"</span>")
          df1$Achievements = paste0("<span style=\"color:#288D55\">",df1$Achievements,"</span>")
          df = rbind(df,df1)
          for (m in unique(pa_m$quarter_year)){
            if(m==q){
              df2 = pa_m[pa_m$quarter_year==q,][-5]
              df = rbind(df,df2)
            }
          }
        }
        df = df[-1,]
      }
        return(df)
        }
```

The apply which i tried

```
my_fun <- function(q){
      df1 = pa_qtr[pa_qtr$Period==q,]
      df1$Period = paste0("<span style=\"color:#288D55\">",df1$Period,"</span>")
      df1$Plans = paste0("<span style=\"color:#288D55\">",df1$Plans,"</span>")
      df1$Achievements = paste0("<span style=\"color:#288D55\">",df1$Achievements,"</span>")
      df = rbind(df,df1)


    }
    df = do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(pa_qtr$Period), my_fun))
    
    my_fun2 <- function(m,my_fun){
      if (m == q) {
        df2 = pa_mon[pa_mon$qtr_yr == q, ][-5]
        df = rbind(df,df2)
      }
    }
    df = do.call(cbind,lapply(unique(pa_mon$qtr_yr), my_fun2))
```

DT::datatable(plans_achievements(pa_m[pa_m$inc=="vate",],pa_q[pa_q$inc=="vate",]), rownames = F,escape = FALSE,selection=list(mode="single",target="row"),options = list(pageLength = 50,scrollX = TRUE,dom = 'tp',ordering=F,columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(0)),list(className = 'dt-left', targets = '_all'))))

[image: current output] [image: excepted output]

Answer (score 0):

### Why you get the error `comparison is possible only for atomic and list types`

I will answer your original question first:

You get the error because you haven't defined `q` as a variable inside the function `my_fun2`. Since you haven't defined this variable, R will look for it in the global environment. There R will find the **function** `q()` (used to quit R). So you get the error message `comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types` because R thinks you are trying to compare a number `m` with the function `q`.

Here is a small example to make it easy to see:

```r
# Run this in a clean environment

m <- 1

m == b # Understandable error message - "b" is not found
m == q # Your error - because R thinks you are comparing m to a function
```

You fix this error by making sure that `q` is defined inside your function. Either by creating it inside the function, or by supplying it as an input argument.

### A possible solution for your problem

As I understand your code, you want to format, merge and sort the values in `pa_q` and `pa_m`, to display them in a html table.

Under is a possible solution, using tidyverse and vectorized operations, rather than a loop or apply functions. Vectorized functions are typically your fastest option in R, as I know you want to optimize your code.

```r
library(dplyr)


plans_achievements <- function(pa_m, pa_q) {
  
  # I've modified the logic a bit: there is no need to wrap the full function in
  # an else statement, since we can return early if the data has no rows
  if (nrow(pa_m) == 0 && nrow(pa_q == 0)) {
    df = data.frame(a = c(""), b = c("No Data Available"))
    colnames(df) = ""
    
    return(df)
    
  }
  
  pa_q <- 
    pa_q %>% 
    # Select and rename the columns vi need
    select(inc, Period = quarter_year, Plans, Achievements, date) %>% 
    # Format the values
    mutate(
      Period = paste0("<span style=\"color:#288D55\">", Period,"</span>"),
      Plans = paste0("<span style=\"color:#288D55\">", Plans,"</span>"),
      Achievements = paste0("<span style=\"color:#288D55\">", Achievements,"</span>")
    )
  
  pa_m <- 
    pa_m %>% 
    # Select and rename the columns we need
    select(inc, Period = month_year, Plans, Achievements, date) #%>% 
  
  # Combine the datasets
  bind_rows(
    pa_q, 
    pa_m
  ) %>% 
    # Make sure that R understand date as a date value
    mutate(
      date = lubridate::dmy(date)
    ) %>% 
    # Sort by date
    arrange(desc(date)) %>% 
    # Remove columns we do not need
    select(-date, -inc)
  
}


DT::datatable(
  plans_achievements(
    pa_m[pa_m$inc=="vate",],
    pa_q[pa_q$inc=="vate",]
  ), 
  rownames = FALSE,
  escape = FALSE,
  selection = list(mode = "single", target = "row"),
  options = list(
    pageLength = 50,
    scrollX = TRUE,
    dom = 'tp',
    ordering = FALSE,
    columnDefs = list(
      list(className = 'dt-left', targets = '_all')
    )
  )
)
```

Hopefully this solves your problem.

Comment: when i tried to give more that one input it shows  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument "q" is missing, with no default

Comment: You get that error message when you don't supply the inputs that your function requires. You could supply `q = <value>` to `lapply()`, but I don't think it would do what you want. As stated above, you need to adapt my example to your use case, since I don't know what you want to achieve. It would be a lot easier to help you if you (1) explained what you want your code to do, and (2) provided a minimal reprex. Read more about how to do that here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my answer with a possible solution for you. I don't use apply functions, but rather vectorized functions from the tidyverse, which I believe is a better solution. Hopefully this solves your problem.

Comment: And i am also getting an error using your code  Problem with `mutate()` column `date`.
i `date = lubridate::dmy(date)`.
i All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Comment: In the example data in your question, `pa_q$date` and `pa_m$date` is a character vector on the format  `dd-mm-yyyy`, for example `"15-06-2020"`. `lubridate::dmy()` should work fine with this input - and it is working on my computer - so your problem might be with something else. Do you have the package lubridate installed? Is your data different from the one you supplied with your question?

Comment: its working fine jpiversen the issue is in date format but if you change this using apply it will be more useful

Comment: To be honest, I see no benefit of using apply functions here. It will make your code less readable and probably not much faster if at all. Using vectorized code will make it much faster and more readable. 

Further, it is not straightforward to use apply functions here, since you've got two nested loops and they are not independent (`q` is showing up in both and both are reliant on `df` which is defined outside the loop). It would probably take you longer to come up with some clever apply functions than to just rewrite your code using the tidyverse method in my suggestion.

Comment: Thank you so much @jpiversen sure i will check and  will follow your guidance

Comment: just need on small help jpiversen is it possible to show the q1 in the first line refer the above image

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t understand the question. I see the image, but what do you mean by «to show the q1 in the first line»?

Comment: client needs the data should be in proper order ex: quarter [q1-apr,may,june] [q2-july,aug,sep] [q3-oct,nov,dec] [q4-jan,feb,mar] the period should be in this format for more clarification kindly run the for loop code

Comment: I just sorted the values by the date variable. If that is not how you want to sort the table you could quite easily create a new column based on Period to sort on.

Comment: i update the images of current output and expected output take a look and let me know how to tackle this sorting issue

Comment: My mistake, I sorted the values descending. Change `arrange(desc(date))` to `arrange(date)` (ascending order is the default for `arrange()`.

Comment: previously i tried but i didn't get the expected output its showing [apr,may,june-q1] instead of [q1-apr,may,june] @jpiversen